# find (mmin) gives unexpected results

Tags: 20.04, find, systemd-journald, timestamp

I originally wanted to `find` which files have been modified in the last week (before the unexpected results led me onto the quest I describe in this question), so I ran this following command (10080 minutes = 1 week):

```
find . -mmin -10080 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

But to my big surprise, a seemingly never-ending stream of files flew across the screen.

I tried to narrow it down, and found this:

- `find . -mmin -6704 -exec ls -lh {} \;` returns nothing, while
- `find . -mmin -6705 -exec ls -lh {} \;` returns about 200 files, all of which seem like old files.

I thought there might be something wrong with my version of `find`, perhaps `-mmin` used hours or days or something, instead of the usual minutes. But I waited 5 minutes, and got the expected result:

- `find . -mmin -6709 -exec ls -lh {} \;` returned nothing, while
- `find . -mmin -6710 -exec ls -lh {} \;` returned the same 200 files.

**This amount of minutes points to the exact time of `Sat Apr 22, 5:20 AM` (my local time).**

Most of these files are modified some time in 2022, but there are also some even older files, such as this:

```
$ stat 20130624_141025.jpg 
  File: 20130624_141025.jpg
  Size: 2949509     Blocks: 5768       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10303h/66307d   Inode: 4066298     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  user)   Gid: ( 1000/  user)
Access: 2023-03-26 04:35:47.518978140 +0200
Modify: 2013-06-24 11:10:25.000000000 +0200
Change: 2022-10-09 03:28:01.112446868 +0200
 Birth: -
```

I don't understand why files like this seem to have been modified last Saturday according to `find` (but not according to `stat`).

**What could possibly cause these results?**

Here are the `journalctl` entries from around that time:

```
april 22 05:16:40 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:16:40 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:16:53 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:16:53 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:17:01 host CRON[906135]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
april 22 05:17:01 host CRON[906136]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
april 22 05:17:01 host CRON[906135]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
april 22 05:17:19 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:17:19 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:17:29 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:17:29 host rtkit-daemon[1258]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
april 22 05:20:08 host dbus-daemon[1639]: [session uid=1000 pid=1639] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1635 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
april 22 05:20:08 host systemd[1627]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
april 22 05:20:08 host tracker-extract[906637]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
april 22 05:20:08 host tracker-extract[906637]: Setting priority nice level to 19
april 22 05:20:08 host dbus-daemon[1639]: [session uid=1000 pid=1639] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
april 22 05:20:08 host systemd[1627]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
april 22 05:20:11 host gnome-shell[6085]: Warning: disabling flag --expose_wasm due to conflicting flags
april 22 05:20:18 host systemd[1627]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
april 22 05:20:23 host /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1725]: (EE) event11 - SYNA2393:00 06CB:7A13 Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
april 22 05:20:23 host /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1725]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.15.5/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html for details
april 22 05:25:59 host gnome-shell[6085]: Warning: disabling flag --expose_wasm due to conflicting flags
april 22 05:29:54 host systemd[1627]: vte-spawn-10cbca7f-6f32-4715-9d7b-dd17ed636519.scope: Succeeded.
```

The same information is in `/var/log/syslog`. I can't see anything relevant in `dmesg` or `auth.log`. Please let me know if there are other relevant logs or information you need.

Although it was an **ahem** unusual time of day, I was in fact awake and on my computer at this time, so I may or may not have triggered anything and everything that might be in the log. I just don't understand what could have caused these weird results from `find`...?

Find version: `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0)`
Kernel/release: `5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `ls -lh` without having `find` filter out directories, so if the parent directories of the listed files were modified on that date, then `find` would match on those directories, run `ls -lh` with those directories as the arguments, and thus result in listing out the *contents* of those directories, showing you these files.

Use `-type f` (or maybe `! -type d`)s o that you filter out directories, or the `-ls` action instead of running `-exec ls -lh {} \;`, or `ls -ldh`, to list the directories themselves instead of their contents.

Comment: Aaah, that makes so much sense, and your fix works perfectly. In hindsight, I should probably have realized that from the output (which I did think looked pretty weird). Thank you for your swift answer!